# Map a port to another on same machine

Tags: linux, iptables, port-forwarding, nat, tcpdump

I have all the traffic coming on port 22. I chose a random port 221 on which i want all of the traffic to be routed.

This is the rule i used

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 22 -j REDIRECT --to-port 221
or  iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 221

iptable --list
target     prot opt source               destination         
           tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
           tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:221
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http-alt
```

I am checking the traffic using command

```
tcpdump -i any port 221
```

Nothing is routed to port 221. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The ingress interface sees packets before the IP stack does. I.e. no NAT effects are seens on packets which originate outside the system. Their target port is changed, you just do not see it with `tcpdump`. You can see it with the packjet counters in your `filter/INPUT` chain, though.

This is different with locally generated packets. They reach the IP stack before they reach the interface. Thus you see the packets on the loopback interface with the DNAT effects.